# export and import data when some string variable embedded new line

Tags: r, csv, sas, dbf

Suppose I have variable s with this code:

```
s <- "foo\nbar"
```

Then change it to data.frame

```
s2 <- data.frame(s)
```

Now s2 is a data.frame with one records, next I export to a csv file with:

```
write.csv(s2, file = "out.csv", row.names = F)
```

Then I open it with notepad, the "foo\nbar" was flown into two lines. With SAS import:

```
proc import datafile = "out.csv" out = out dbms = csv replace;
run;
```

I got two records, one is '"foo', the other is 'bar"', which is not expected.

After struggling for a while, I found if I export from R with foreign package like this:

```
write.dbf(s2, 'out.dbf')
```

Then import with SAS:

```
proc import datafile = "out.dbf" out = out dbms = dbf replace;
run;
```

Everything works nice and got one records in sas, the value seems to be 'foo bar'.
Does this mean csv is a bad choice when dealing with data, compared with dbf? Are there any other solutions or explanations to this?

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file stands for comma-separated-version.  This means that each line in the file should contain a list of values separated by a comma.  SAS imported the file correctly based on the definition of the CSV file (ie. 2 lines = 2 rows).

The problem you are experiencing is due to the `\n` character(s) in your string.  This sequence of characters happens to represent a newline character, and this is why the R `write.csv()` call is creating two lines instead of putting it all on one.

I'm not an expert in R so I can't tell you how to either modify the call to `write.csv()` or mask the `\n` value in the input string to prevent it from writing out the newline character.

The reason you don't have this problem with .dbf is probably because it doesn't care about commas or newlines to indicate when new variables or rows start, it must have it's own special sequence of bytes that indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

DBF - is a database formats, which are always easier to work with because they have variable types/lengths embedded in their structure.

With a CSV or any other delimited file you have to have documentation included to know the file structure.

The benefit of CSV is smaller file sizes and compatibility across multiple OS and applications. For a while Excel (2007?) no longer supported DBF for example.

Comment: If insisting on using csv file, as Robert mentioned, masking the special characters like '\n' could be a working around way. CSV is indeed handy to take a quick look what the data looks like. I always got frustrated when dealing with free texts. If the data is really big, RSqllite could also be a choice, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert says you will need to mask the new line value. For example:

```
replace_linebreak <- function(x,...){
  gsub('\n','|n',x)
}   

s3 <- replace_linebreak(s2$s)
```

This replaces `\n` with `|n`, which would you would then need to replace when you import again. Obviously what you choose to mask it with will depend on your data.